# Lightswitch Updating() method not saving any data in DB

Tags: c#, entity, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I am trying to save the entity data using General methods of lightswitch, which is Updating. Below is the following code. I am not able to figure out what I am missing. There is no error in the code or in the UI. Its just that nothing gets saved.

```
partial void viewFamilyProcessDatas_Updating(viewFamilyProcessData entity)
    {

        var AutoAddMissingListing = entity.AutoAddMissingListing;
        var AutoAddOddLots = entity.AutoAddOddLots;
        var DefaultFilterValue = entity.DefaultFilterValue;
        var ExcludeZeroNumberOfUnits = entity.ExcludeZeroNumberOfUnits;
        //objFamilyProcessData.FamilyID = entity.FamilyID;
        var IgnoreForPricing = entity.IgnoreForPricing;
        var LimitEndDate = entity.LimitEndDate;
        var OffsetFromMaxAsAtDate = entity.OffsetFromMaxAsAtDate;
        var PrefilterConstituents = entity.PrefilterConstituents;
        var TimeDataExpires = entity.TimeDataExpires;

        entity.AutoAddMissingListing = AutoAddMissingListing;
        entity.AutoAddOddLots = AutoAddOddLots;
        entity.DefaultFilterValue = DefaultFilterValue;
        entity.ExcludeZeroNumberOfUnits = ExcludeZeroNumberOfUnits;
        entity.IgnoreForPricing = IgnoreForPricing;
        entity.LimitEndDate = LimitEndDate;
        entity.OffsetFromMaxAsAtDate = OffsetFromMaxAsAtDate;
        entity.PrefilterConstituents = PrefilterConstituents;
        entity.TimeDataExpires = TimeDataExpires;

        //this.DataWorkspace.SolaDBServerData.Details.DiscardChanges();
        entity.Details.DiscardChanges();



    }
```

Comment: You're not actually doing anything, plus you're calling DiscardChanges(). Chances are your actual DataSource is not updatable.  First thing you should do is verify that every table in your database has a PrimaryKey.  Then verify that all ForeignKeys are defined back to a PrimaryKey.  Then update your lightswitch DataSource. Then delete the Updating method above as it isn't actually doing anything.

Comment: Hi @Kris My DataSource is updatable. I have verified that every table in my DB has a PK. Also all FKs are defined back to PK. I have updated the LS Datasource. But I cannot delete the Updating method. Because I am trying to save the data directly to a View. TimeDataExpires Property in my view requires data to be saved like this. Can you please suggest me how can I add C# code to be able to update the data on the entity

Comment: HI @Kris, If I remove the DiscardChanges() line then this would give me an error saying that "Update or insert of view or function 'dbo.viewFamilyProcessData' failed because it contains a derived or constant field."

Comment: You could always discard, then manually update the destination tables.

Comment: Manually??? Can you please be more specific? Also can you please give some examples or links from which I can take help. And also please keep in mind, I need to solve this problem using the C# code - Updating method only.

Comment: Use EF6 + LINQ or SQL INSERT/UPDATE statements, or a WebAPI or WCF web service request... or do it the lightswitch way but on a table level, not a view level.  I dunno, use your imagination.

Comment: Imagination!!! I am trying to imagine since last 2 weeks. Its the 3rd week going now. Also I cannot use any of the suggested things that you said. If I could, then I have already solved this problem using HttpHandler and Stored Procedure. But my requirement is that I need to solve this using LS Updating() method. Also I have to use SQL views to render this Add/Edit screen because there is a TimeStamp data type in the screen (entity.TimeDataExpires) which requires me to do all this fuss and pressure that I am going through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this finally came to this:

```
partial void vwFamilyProcessDatas_Updating(vwFamilyProcessData entity)
    {
        if(entity.Details.EntityState.ToString() == "Modified")
        {
            var AutoAddMissingListing = entity.AutoAddMissingListing;
            var AutoAddOddLots = entity.AutoAddOddLots;
            var DefaultFilterValue = entity.DefaultFilterValue;
            var ExcludeZeroNumberOfUnits = entity.ExcludeZeroNumberOfUnits;
            var IgnoreForPricing = entity.IgnoreForPricing;
            var LimitEndDate = entity.LimitEndDate;
            var OffsetFromMaxAsAtDate = entity.OffsetFromMaxAsAtDate;
            var PrefilterConstituents = entity.PrefilterConstituents;
            var TimeDataExpires = entity.TimeDataExpires;

            tblFamily objFamily = tblFamilies.Where(f => f.FamilyID == entity.FamilyID).Single();
            objFamily.AutoAddMissingListing = AutoAddMissingListing;
            objFamily.AutoAddOddLots = AutoAddOddLots;
            objFamily.DefaultFilterValue = DefaultFilterValue;
            objFamily.ExcludeZeroNumberOfUnits = ExcludeZeroNumberOfUnits;
            objFamily.IgnoreForPricing = IgnoreForPricing;
            objFamily.LimitEndDate = LimitEndDate;
            objFamily.OffsetFromMaxAsAtDate = OffsetFromMaxAsAtDate;
            objFamily.PrefilterConstituents = PrefilterConstituents;
            objFamily.TimeDataExpires = TimeSpan.Parse(TimeDataExpires);

            entity.Details.DiscardChanges();
        }}
```